# How do I get the DLL name/path from the DLLImport attribute using PEReader from System.Reflection?

Tags: c#, dllimport, system.reflection

I am writing a utility that disassembles dll/exe files written in c#, and then scans all types inside this file for the presence of methods imported from an unmanaged DLL. I need to get information about each imported method, including the name/path of the DLL from which this method is imported, that is, the value of the first argument of the DllImport attribute. Let's assume that there is such a function declaration in the dll/exe file:

```
[DllImport("C:\\TestDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void HelloWorld();
```

I am new to reflection and am trying to use `PEReader` to view all types and search for functions imported from DLL. I'm calling `GetImport()` from the `System.Reflection.Metadata.MethodDefinition` to determine whether the current MethodDefinition is an imported method. Via `GetImport().Attributes` I hope to get all the DllImport parameters, including the path of this DLL, but this does not give the desired result:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToBinary, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var peReader = new PEReader(fileStream))
    {
        var mdReader = peReader.GetMetadataReader();

        foreach (var typeHandler in mdReader.TypeDefinitions)
        {
            var typeDef = mdReader.GetTypeDefinition(typeHandler);

            foreach (var methodHandler in typeDef.GetMethods())
            {
                var methodDef = mdReader.GetMethodDefinition(methodHandler);
                var import = methodDef.GetImport();
                if(import.Module.IsNil)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                //Returns "CallingConventionCdecl" but not ""C:\\TestDll.dll," CallingConventionCdecl":
                var dllImportParameters = import.Attributes.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is, `GetMethod().Attributes` returns all DLLImport parameters except the library name/path from which the method is imported.

How do I get the DLL path from the first argument of DllImport?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the variables with a debugger? I suspect `import` does have the right fields, but they're not part of the `ToString()` representation.

Comment: @PMF You're right! I don't know how I didn't see it last time, but import has a Module property that returns an instance of System.Reflection.Metadata.ModuleReferenceHandle. With MetaDataReader.GetModuleReference (moduleReferenceHandle) it can be converted to System.Reflection.Metadata.ModuleReference. In turn, an instance of ModuleReference has a Name property that returns StringHandle and can also be converted to string using MetaDataReader.GetString (stringHandle). This is the name/path of the DLL. I don't know how I missed it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. So `import` has a `Module` property that returns an instance of `System.Reflection.Metadata.ModuleReferenceHandle`. With `MetaDataReader.GetModuleReference(moduleReferenceHandle)` it can be converted to `System.Reflection.Metadata.ModuleReference`. In turn, an instance of `ModuleReference` has a `Name` property that returns `StringHandle` and can also be converted to string using `MetaDataReader.GetString(stringHandle)`. This is the name/path of the DLL.

Full resolution of the issue:

```
string dllPath = mdReader.GetString(mdReader.GetModuleReference(import.Module).Name);
```